How do I specify compiler toolchain for specific modules in yocto
We have a huge project.
The project is based out of GCC 6.4.0
There is a feasibility being conducted , if it can be upgraded to GNU v11.2
I need to check only if my module .
How do I compile only my modules against GNU v11.2 to verify if they at least compile.

What I would do, hypotheses:

Download the poky Kirkstone version, configure the MACHINE for some QEMU of your architecture, generate the toolchain using the meta-toolchain recipe that contains GCC 11, install the generated SDK, and compile your project.


git clone -b kirkstone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
cd poky
source oe-init-build-env


Generating toolchain for ARM

MACHINE=qemuxarm bitbake meta-toolchain


Generating toolchain for AARCH64

MACHINE=qemuarm64 bitbake meta-toolchain


Generating toolchain for x86-64

MACHINE=qemux86-64 bitbake meta-toolchain


Then access tmp/deploy/sdk and install the generated .sh file, ready toolchain generated for one of the above ARCH's.

A slightly easier path, download the toolchain with version 11 directly from the ARM website, install and configure the environment variables.
ARM GNU Toolchain Downloads

The problem you may encounter with both solutions is dependencies! Perhaps you will have to compile each one beforehand.
